# Inequality for an expectation involving a product of densities

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, improper-integrals, integral-inequality

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two real (independent) random variables with pdfs $f$ and $g$ respectively, and such that their expectations exist and are finite and $\mathbb{E}[X] \leq \mathbb{E}[Y]$. Define a new pdf as $$h(z) = \frac{f(z) g(z)}{\int f(z) g(z) \; d z}$$ Let $Z$ be a real random variable with pdf $h$ (also independent of $X$ and $Y$). Assume $\mathbb{E}[Z]$ exists and is finite. I wonder what are sufficient and necessary conditions for the following to hold
$$
\mathbb{E}[X]
\leq
\mathbb{E}[Z]
\leq
\mathbb{E}[Y]
$$
Thanks

Comment: It's false in general (let the supports of $X$ and $Y$ be largely disjoint, except for a tiny overlap near some arbitrary value unrelated to $EX$ and $EY$.  Such as, $X$ is a mixture of uniform on $[0,1]$ and uniform on $[a, a+1/10]$, with mixing weights $99/100$ and $1/100$; let $Y$ be a mixture of uniform on $[2,3]$ and $[a,a+1/10]$ with the same weights.

Comment: I completely agree, there are plenty of counter-examples. I'm looking for sufficient and/or necessary conditions. For example, what if $f$ and $g$ have support $\mathbb{R}$ and they are both unimodal and symmetric?